# Looping over a matrix - vector multiplication, with elements of both changing with each round

Tags: r

I have a large data set consisting of two matrices and a vector. One of the two matrices and the vector have elements that change. I would like to loop over every possible vector-matrix combination, add over every column and row for each iteration, and finally store these results in a vector.

The vector has one element with "1", the rest 0's. The matrix has 1's everywhere apart from one smaller block of 0's along its diagonal.

The vector and the matrix are not independent from each other, the location of the 0's of the matrix depends on the location of the 1 in the vector.

For example, the elements of the matrix is grouped with size 2*2, then when the vector has 1 in the first or second element, the matrix has 0's in the first 2*2 block along the diagonal. If the 1 is located in the third element of the vector, the block of 0's in the matrix moves to [3:4 , 3:4], and so on.

I give a small example with matrices `a` and `b`, and vector `c`:

```
a <- matrix(1:36, nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

In this example, I group together elements along blocks of size 3*3. As I don't know how to loop very well, I already prepare all the combinations for `b` and `c`:

```
b <- matrix(rep(1, times = 36), nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)

b1 <- b
b1[1:3,1:3] <- 0
b2 <- b
b2[4:6,4:6] <- 0

c1 <- rep(0, times = 6)
c1[1] <- 1
c2 <- rep(0, times = 6)
c2[2] <- 1
c3 <- rep(0, times = 6)
c3[3] <- 1
c4 <- rep(0, times = 6)
c4[4] <- 1
c5 <- rep(0, times = 6)
c5[5] <- 1
c6 <- rep(0, times = 6)
c6[6] <- 1

d1 <- sum(colSums(b1 * diag(as.vector(a %*% c1), nrow = 6)))
d2 <- sum(colSums(b1 * diag(as.vector(a %*% c2), nrow = 6)))
d3 <- sum(colSums(b1 * diag(as.vector(a %*% c3), nrow = 6)))
d4 <- sum(colSums(b2 * diag(as.vector(a %*% c4), nrow = 6)))
d5 <- sum(colSums(b2 * diag(as.vector(a %*% c5), nrow = 6)))
d6 <- sum(colSums(b2 * diag(as.vector(a %*% c6), nrow = 6)))
```

The multiplication between both matrices is an element wise one.

I store the results in `results`

```
results <- cbind(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6)
```

that gives:

```
     d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6
[1,] 75 78 81 30 33 36
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently using loops? I would also really appreciate if I could define inside of the code how big the blocks are. In my data, the blocks are around 50*50. Also, I have several blocks in my dataset..

Comment: Hello! Can you please tell us a bit about what you want to use these structures for? What process do they contribute to?

Comment: With so many zeros in the vector and matrix, there is likely a simpler formula for the result of the product than the general formula for a matrix-vector product.  For example, if entry `j` of `v` is `1` and the rest are zero, then `A %*% v` is simply `sum(A[,j])`.  You can probably make use of this to speed up your calculation (which I don't quite follow).

Comment: Thanks for providing more info! Have you thought about handling your data as data frames or tibbles instead of as matrices? This might make it easier to read, so that other people who help with your work (e.g. on Stack Overflow) or take over from you in future, will more easily understand your code. It is also likely to be the case that there's a well-known solution to your problem when the data is labelled up and presented as a table (e.g. with one column for country name, one column for economic sector, and then further numeric columns as necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- matrix(1:36, nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)
b <- matrix(rep(1, times =  36), nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)
b1 <- b
b1[1:3,1:3] <- 0
b2 <- b
b2[4:6,4:6] <- 0
```

my loop codes...

```
for (i in seq(6)){
temp = rep(0, 6)
temp[i] = 1
assign(paste('c', i, sep = ''), temp)
}

for (i in seq(6)){ 
cx = get(paste('c', i, sep = ''))
if(i<4){
  px = sum(colSums(b1 * diag(as.vector(a %*% cx), nrow = 6)))
  assign(paste('d', i, sep = ''), px)
} else{
  px = sum(colSums(b2 * diag(as.vector(a %*% cx), nrow = 6)))
  assign(paste('d', i, sep = ''), px)
}
}
```

then the results

```
results <- cbind(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6)
```

Comment: Hi :). Can you add some details to you answer, please? Like how your answer solves the problem?

Comment: The code works well :) Just a question, in my data I have many blocks of code. Would, for example, if(i>10 | i < 20) ... work under the first if?

Comment: Thank you! `else if` helps for finding for several conditions